# PHPUnit & Symfony: Mock Kernel Error

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to test a service which takes the `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel` as a dependency.

This is what i do in order to mock the kernel.

```
$this->kernel = $this->getMock('Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface');
$this->kernel->expects($this->any())
     ->method('getEnvironment')
     ->will($this->returnValue('dev'));
```

When i run the test, i get something as the following error.

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare static foo\foo\WebTestCase::$kernel as non static foo\foo\MyTest::$kernel in ...

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error message carefully. `WebTestCase::$kernel` is a static variable, which means you cannot access it with `$this`. An attempt to override it as an instance variable causes this error.

Besides, `WebTestCase` class is not meant to be a base class for unit tests where you mock the kernel. It's a class that facilitates writing functional tests, which is why the real kernel is injected into this static variable. If you want to write a unit test and mock the kernel, use the usual `TestCase` class from PHPUnit.